# Do I need extra power supply for NVIDIA Inno 3d graphics card

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card

Initially when I had old pc then I had Inno 3d GF 8600 GTS DDR3 256MB graphics card. But there was extra wire joining card with power supply or something else, I forgot that.

Now I have [this motherboard](http://necola.net/product-details.aspx?id=758&colid=0)

I want to know that what should I insert in that 6 pin socket. Is that card compatible with this motherboard?

The pictures are below.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that the card as a power socket I would say that you do need to connect it up.

The motherboard shouldn't matter as long as it has the necessary expansion slot, it's the extra lead from the power supply that you need.

Comment: Actually i have no cord coming from power supply that has 6 pins . i have normal sata and ide power supply

Comment: @user105919 - What about on the old PC? Do you still have that. There should be a lead you can use from that. If not you'll need to buy a new lead.

Comment: i removed that about 2 years ago , so i don't that now. I just saved the Graphics card. So you mean are those type of Cords available in market. I mean does those plug in in SATA or IDE socket and other end in card??

Comment: @user105919 - Ah. Yes the cords should be available. You want something like this - http://www.google.co.uk/products/catalog?q=graphics+card+power+cord&hl=en&rlz=1C1GPCK_enGB424GB424&prmd=imvns&biw=1012&bih=875&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=18056998161955629313&sa=X&ei=_jTKTqODKc-j8gPZzJSDAQ&ved=0CIoBEPMCMAA This is molex, but I would expect SATA ones to be available too.

Comment: thanks i have just ordered that. I know that my motherboard is not powerful and processor is P4 2.5Ghz. Is that anything to do with GFX card

Comment: one more thing , if i use that card without that cable . will that be a problem. The computer does start without any problem. I just want to make sure that motherboard does not get burn off

Comment: @user105919 - as long as the power supply is adequate you should be OK